# How is key length of feistel cipher calculated?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, blocksize

In Feitsel Algorithim

If our block size is n, then our key length would be n x 2^n .

But this does not make sense for me. 
For example: Let's assume that we have 4 bit block size. If our block size is 4, how can the key length be 64 bit?

Comment: The key size is largely independent of the block size, this also holds for Feistel-ciphers. For example [Twofish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twofish) was a Feistel cipher and has 128bit block size and 128, 192 and 256 bit key size support.

Comment: okay, Let's assume that we have a 20 bits plain text and we want to encrypt it. Because of 4-bit block size we have 5 different blocks. We take the first block which is 4-bit and our key which is  64-bit. How can we use 64-bit key to encrypt 4 bit plain text( one block )

Comment: you could use different parts of the key each round or combine certain key bits together for each round.

Comment: "If our block size is n, then our key length would be X 2^n ", according to this, if n is 4, then the key length is 2 ^ 4 (4 bits), not 2 ^ 64 (64 bits), right? I don't see where your 64 bit key comes from.

Comment: @EllaRose yes, I am sorry I put the formula wrong, and I fixed it ( n times 2 the power of n)

Comment: @enesK Can I ask where your formula n * (2 ^ N) comes from?

Comment: @EllaRose It is from the Cryptography and Network Security Book by William Stallings,  page 71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some confusion here: The formula N * (2 ** N) for key size is for *ideal* block ciphers that select one of (2 ** N)! permutations. Shortly after that formula, your book starts to go into the Feistel construction (emphasis is mine):

> The Feistel Cipher
>
> Feistel proposed [FEIS73] that we can approximate the ideal block cipher by utilizing
> the concept of a product cipher, which is the execution of two or more simple ciphers
> in sequence in such a way that the final result or product is cryptographically stronger
> than any of the component ciphers. **The essence of the approach is to develop a block
> cipher with a key length of k bits and a block length of n bits, allowing a total of 2 ^ K possible transformations, rather than the 2 ^ N! transformations available with the ideal
> block cipher**

So the idea is to compromise on the huge key length and sacrifice the ability of picking one of *all* possible permutations, to utilize a smaller key that can select one of *enough* possible permutations. A cipher will typically use a key length that is equal to it's target block size, to simplify the key addition layer.